# Detect mobile device in Edge (on Surface Tab)

Tags: responsive

I'm using:

```
@media only screen and (pointer: coarse) {}
```

As a media query to select non desktop devices and on Android Chrome this works fine but in Edge on the Surface Tab devices this doesn't work. While `pointer` is supported in Edge browsers.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a Modernizr extension called Detectizr (https://github.com/barisaydinoglu/Detectizr) which is adding classes to your HTML tag.

When you inspect the element you will see something like this:

```
<html class="js js no-touch desktop landscape windows windowsnt windowsnt_0 64bit chrome chrome71 chrome71_0 webkit">
```

As you can imagine the classes will change depending of your browser, OS, etc

Comment: I've opted to use the `current-device` package. But I'll keep `Detectizr` in the back of my head if issues arise.